# Create mailto link that has attachment stored in db

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mailto

Using asp.net/vb.net is it possible to dynamically generate a mailto hyperlink that attaches a particular Word document that resides on the server (either in a db or on the server's file system)?

(I searched online but could not find the answer. I assume that the html "mailto" is limited to attachments that are on the clients machine.)

If it's not supported in mailto, do you have any other suggestions as to a solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: i'm afraid that isn't possible. you should just use a link generated by your server in the body.

Comment: mailto: doesn't officially support attachments